# Add one more option in select element using Illuminate\html

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

I have a create method like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = App\CategoryModel::pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('posts.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

and I want to add some options to select element using `Illuminate\html`.

This is my select element:

```
{!! Form::label('category', 'Category') !!}
{!! Form::select(null, $categories, null, ['class' => 'form', 'style' => 'height: 40px;', 'name' => 'category']); !!}
```

But I want to add one more option element like this:

```
<option disabled selected> -- Select a category -- </option>
```

What should I do?

Comment: This not possible with default functionality, but you can add additional Form helpers using a [Macro](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#custom-macros)

Comment: If I use Macro, it's just like writing HTML. Do you think I should write HTML or use Macro? Because I read some articles about it and they told `Illuminate\html` is used to reduce code.

Comment: I'm talking about `Form::macro` not `HTML::macro()`. `Form::macro()` allows you to extend the Form facade with your own methods. If you want this, I'll create that function for you and place that as a answer

Comment: If I write that, which file should I write? I want to write to use many times.

Comment: You can write your macro under app forlder(i.e/ app/lib/helper.php). Also you need to register this into laravel autoloader...

Comment: Please write an answer about your own macro and show me how to register it. If it work, I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, wait for min.

Comment: Macro is ready, Please check my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custom macro to fulfill this. Check below step by code:

*1) Create macro under* `app/lib/macro.php`

```
<?php
//My custom macro...
Form::macro('mySelect', function($name, $list = array(), $selected = null, $disabled = null, $options = array())
{
    $selected = $this->getValueAttribute($name, $selected);
    $disabled = $this->getValueAttribute($name, $disabled);

    $options['id'] = $this->getIdAttribute($name, $options);

    if ( ! isset($options['name'])) $options['name'] = $name;

    $html = array();

    foreach ($list as $list_el)
    {
        $selectedAttribute = $this->getSelectedValue($list_el['id'], $selected);
        $disabledAttribute = $this->getSelectedValue($list_el['id'], $disabled);
        $option_attr = array('value' => e($list_el['id']), 'selected' => $selectedAttribute, 'disabled' => $disabledAttribute);
        $html[] = '<option'.$this->html->attributes($option_attr).'>'.e($list_el['value']).'</option>';
    }

    $options = $this->html->attributes($options);

    $list = implode('', $html);

    return "<select{$options}>{$list}</select>";
});
```

*2) Register macro into* `app/Providers/MacroServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\Macros\Macros;
use Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class MacroServiceProvider
 * @package App\Providers
 */
class MacroServiceProvider extends HtmlServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        require base_path() . '/app/lib/macro.php';
    }

.
.
.
}
```

*3) Use my custom macro*:

```
{!!Form::mySelect('category',array(array('id' => '0', 'value'=>'-- Select a category --'), array('id' => '1', 'value'=>'My value1'), array('id' => '2', 'value'=>'My value2')), 0, 0) !!}
```

Tested with Laravel 5.2.

Comment: @Yachi웃: Did you check this?

Comment: Please perform step `2) Register macro into app/Providers/MacroServiceProvider.php` as described

Comment: As I tested before place this answer and it's working fine.

Comment: I did create this file. I use laravel 5.4, will it make any trouble?

Comment: @Yachi웃: Updated step 2), check and correct boot method as well inclusion.

Comment: Also make sure about the `app/lib/macro.php` path

Comment: Should we load `MacroServiceProvider.php` file?

Comment: Yes, check your `config/app.php` for `providers` array. It should be there

Comment: I still have one problem, if I use `$categories = App\CategoryModel::get(['name', 'id'])->toArray();`, it will get error when I merge it, please help me. I used `pluck` method and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepend()` Laravel helper:

```
{!! Form::label('category', 'Category') !!}
{!! Form::select(null, 
    ["value" => "Select a category", "id" => 0] + $categories, 
    null,
    ['class' => 'form', 'style' => 'height: 40px;', 'name' => 'category']) !!}
```

Check the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-prepend) for further information.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it doesn't work, because pluck method returns an object.

Comment: @Yachi웃 You are completely right, pluck returns a collection, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new value on the $categories array with [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
{{
Form::select(
    null,
    array_merge(['' => ['label' => '-- Select a category --', 'disabled' => true], $categories),
    null,
    ['class' => 'form', 'style' => 'height: 40px;', 'name' => 'category']
}}
```

Comment: I think you can't merge with pluck method. It returns that option as I expected, but another option has the object's value, it's `{"6":"Science","5":"Science Fiction"}`